# WordPress form creation plugin that allows: Step 1 > Step 2 > Step 3 > Submit

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking for a WordPress form creation tool (plugin) that supports multi-part forms. For example, step 1 > Step 2 > Step 3 > Finish

Many thanks in advance for recommendations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [cformsII](http://www.deliciousdays.com/cforms-plugin/). This plugin will allow you to create multi-part forms and post data to any page on your site.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [cformsII](http://www.deliciousdays.com/cforms-plugin/) too. Simply Awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Contact Form 7 Multi-Step Forms](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7-multi-step-module/) .

The demo can be seen here 
http://webheadcoder.com/contact-form-7-multi-step-form/